# Wrong 3rd Argument type for LocationEngine and LocationProvider

Tags: search, mapbox-android

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to use the MapboxSearchSdk that mapbox has, however, I get the following error when trying to use it.

**Error:**

Occurs at the following line of code:

`MapboxSearchSdk.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token), LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this));`

*"Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine', required: 'com.mapbox.search.location.LocationProvider'"*

**My Code:**

```
package com.android.takemehome;
import android.app.Application;

import android.util.Log;

import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.search.MapboxSearchSdk;
import com.mapbox.vision.VisionManager;

public class BaseARActivity extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
        VisionManager.init(this, getResources().getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
        Log.e("Map Box ", "Token initialized");

        MapboxSearchSdk.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token), LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this));
    }
}
```

**Guide that I am following:**

I followed the guide on the mapbox website https://docs.mapbox.com/android/search/guides/install/.
For some reason however, I am getting this error. Could someone please help me fix the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix.

I needed to create a `new LocationProvider` to put as the 3rd argument.

So, I just added the following, and now it works:

```
LocationProvider locationProvider = new LocationProvider() {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Point getLocation() {
        return null;
    }
};

MapboxSearchSdk.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token), locationProvider);
```